# Get all the data between Characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I am trying to extract all the variable from the following string;
string = **'factor1|factor2|factor3'** 
This is just a test string. In real string, I do not know the number of factors. What I want is following;

**ID**  |  **Var1** |  **Var2** |  **Var3** |  **VarN** 
 1  Factor1  Factor2 factor3 FactorN

What I have tried is as following but I have to provide everything manually in order to get all the N factors. I want something generic. I have googled a lot and I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

```
 select SUBSTRING('factor1|factor2|factor3'
            ,CHARINDEX('|','factor1|factor2|factor3') + 1
                    ,CHARINDEX('|','factor1|factor2|factor3',CHARINDEX('|','factor1|factor2|factor3')

                                        )
                            -1)
```

Comment: is this SQL Server?  You've tagged the question as [tag:sql] which is NOT the same thing as [tag:sql-server]

Comment: If it *is* for SQL Server, you want to check http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: There are several questions on DBA and StackExchange about splitting concatenated values.  My favorite: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21081/1896.

Comment: Where does this string come from? You really want to use TVPs if you can. Parsing in SQL Server is for the birds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T SQL Table Valued Function to Split a Column on commas](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/t-sql-table-valued-function-to-split-a-column-on-commas)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this question pertains to Microsoft SQL Server:

Identifying the most appropriate solution requires knowing more about:

- What is the source of this string
- What is the goal of splitting it and returning each value as a separate column?

That being said, the way to accomplish this in T-SQL is to use Dynamic SQL to SELECT a series of literal values that are the result of the input string being split. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'factor1|factor2|factor3';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ';

SELECT @SQL += N''''
             + factors.SplitVal
             + N''' AS [Var'
             + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), factors.SplitNum)
             + N'], '
FROM   SQL#.String_Split(@String, N'|', 1) factors;

SET @SQL = STUFF(@SQL, LEN(@SQL), 1, N';');

--PRINT @SQL;

EXEC (@SQL);
```

You can use whatever string splitter you prefer, though SQLCLR-based splitters are the best choice. The one I used is from the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library of SQLCLR functions (which I wrote, but `String_Split` is in the Free version).

This can easily be wrapped in a stored procedure as they can dynamically create their result set structure at runtime. On the other hand, it cannot be used in a TVF (T-SQL or SQLCLR) as those are required to have static result set structures.

Also, this code just returns a single row. The sample result set in the Question has an `ID` field which implies multiple rows. It is not clear, at this point, how that would even be passed in. But, if there are multiple rows then this gets a little more complicated:

- The code presented here can be adapted to return additional rows of static values, combined into a single result set via `UNION ALL` between them
- The code presented here can be adapted to instead dynamically create a local temp table containing the appropriate number of fields, then for each row, create an `INSERT` statement instead of the current `SELECT` to populate the temp table, and finally do a `SELECT * FROM #tmp;`. All of this would be done within the Dynamic SQL, even the final SELECT, so that the temp table can be kept as a local temp table, thereby allowing multiple processes to run at the same time (which would not work if using a global temp table).
- Depending on where the input data is coming from and how it is being used, it is possible that a Table-Valued Parameter (TVP) would be best.
- If this data already exists, as shown, in a table, then SQLCLR is an option as a stored procedure can be created to split a string into any number of fields and return each row as it is read from the table (i.e. streaming the data back). This is more efficient than T-SQL which needs to place all rows either in memory (in the Dynamic SQL local variable) or on disk (in a temp table). There is a stored procedure in the SQL# library (noted above) called `String_SplitResultIntoFields` that handles this particular scenario quite nicely and efficiently. This proc, however, is only available in the Full version (i.e. not free), but the benefit is that it already exists.