# SQL - Convert text to a list of numeric values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, string-splitting

Looking for SQL code to transform the text string `'12,13,14'` to this list of numbers

```
+----+
| 12 |
+----+
| 13 |
+----+
| 14 |
+----+
```

Example:

- table0.params (varchar) field contains this text: `12,13,14`
- table1 has column ID (numeric).

I would like to form a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID in table0.params
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) version 10.50.1600.1

Comment: The correct solution is to properly normalize your data model. Do **not** store comma delimited values in a single column.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) version 10.50.1600.1

Comment: Also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21078/1822

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/9811267/470530

Answer (score 2):

While this question, for the most part, has been asked and answered what at least feels like hundreds of times on here and StackOverflow, because it concerns int values only I will say that:

Given that you are dealing with *only* `INT` values (as the values contained in the delimited string), the fastest way I have come across is to use a splitter that is a) SQLCLR, and b) specialized to only return integers. Since we know what the output type *should*, in the end be, there is no need to waste the extra cycles on passing back a string (slower than passing back an `INT`) only to convert that string into an `INT`. So, for this use case, I created a function that does just this: splits a string and passes back a table of `INT` values. My testing (so far) shows it to be quite a bit faster than the standard splitter that passes back a table of strings (for the same input values, of course). You can find a pre-done SQLCLR function of this in the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/) library (that I created). The function is **SplitInts**. There is also another version of it named **SplitInts4k** that should be used when the input string is guaranteed to be *no more than* 4000 characters. The difference is that the non-4k version uses `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as the input parameter datatype, and that is noticeably slower than `NVARCHAR(4000)`.

You could use it as follows, though it is unclear, if `table0` really is a Table and not an input parameter, how it relates to `table1` if `table0` has more than 1 row:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE [ID] IN (
         SELECT [SplitVal]
         FROM SQL#.String_SplitInts4k(table0.params, N',', 1, 0)
            );
```

Or perhaps:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN SQL#.String_SplitInts4k(@table0.params, N',', 1, 0) ints
        ON ints.[SplitVal] = t1.[ID];
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I've not seen either of the following approaches listed yet, I figured I'd include them.

**If you're running SQL 2016 or later**, take a look at the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function.

**If you're running SQL 2014 or earlier**, you can utilize some XML trickery to split up the string into a table.

Both approaches are as follows:

```
DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(400) = '12,13,14'

-- For SQL 2016 and later
SELECT CAST(value AS INT) AS value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@myString, ',');

-- For SQL 2014 and earlier - Split String via XML
-- Split String via XML
SELECT y.val as value
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@myString, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML) AS xmlRow
) x CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT t.c.value('.', 'int') AS val
    FROM x.xmlRow.nodes('X') AS t(c)
) y
```

DBFiddle can be found [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5c27062c2b81748bc091d1fd94ba0222)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not against using dynamic SQL, the following example should serve your purpose.  @`Inlist` is my substitute for your `table0.params`  (I commented out the actual EXEC command.)

```
DECLARE @InList VARCHAR(100)

SET @InList = '12,13,14'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * ' + 'FROM MyTable ' + 'WHERE Id IN (' + @InList + ') '

PRINT @sql
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```