# Select All Instances of Substring in a String

Tags: sql-server-2012, json, cte, pattern-matching, substring

I have a varchar(max) column that holds a JSON request string. I need a SQL statement for a report that will select all of the instances of that substring. More specifically I need to grab the LoanId Value from that substring entry pulling a result set that contains a row for each LoanId. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A considerably abbreviated JSON string containing the stuff I'm looking for.

```
[
  {"loanId":"1111111111","someotherValue":7},
  {"loanId":"2222222222","someotherValue":4},
  {"loanId":"3333333333","someotherValue":5},
]
```

Comment: I'm actually trying one new solution now based on https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: not as an answer of course, but if possible - migrate to 2016 where JSON supported,

Comment: Can you show what output you want exactly? Are you expecting a row per `loanId`, or a single row with three comma-separated values, or three distinct columns, or ...?

Comment: Output would be a row for every loanid. I updated the op. We’re not able to update to 2016 at this time. It’s on the road map for this year though.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a string splitting function. For simplicity I'm going to use an XML splitter, but you can see lots of discussion about it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21081/1186) and in all the links that points you to.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       nvarchar(max),
   @Delimiter  nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM ( SELECT x = CONVERT(xml, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')) AS a 
          CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i));
GO
```

With the function in place, you can now use it to chop apart this JSON string:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max) = '[
  {"loanId":"1111111111","someotherValue":7},
  {"loanId":"2222222222","someotherValue":4},
  {"loanId":"3333333333","someotherValue":5},
]';

SELECT LoanID = PARSENAME(s2.Item,1) 
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@s, ',') AS s
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(s.Item, ':') AS s2
WHERE s.Item LIKE '%"loanId":"%'
AND s2.Item NOT LIKE '%"loanId"%';
```

Results:

```
LoanID
----------
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
```